# Write a line to a file, but also write previous line if it matches a pattern and exists

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to write a function which reads text from a large file and writes specific blocks of text to another file.

Example file

```
@Tag
Scenario 1:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 2
Scenario 2:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 3
@Tag2
Scenario 3:
   Do thing 1
   Don't do thing 4
```

I'm trying to read through this file line by line (using IFS right now) and want the output to be something like this:

File 1

```
@Tag
Scenario 1:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 2
```

File 2

```
Scenario 2:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 3
```

File 3

```
@Tag2
Scenario 3:
   Do thing 1
   Don't do thing 4
```

I have the pieces in place to read through the file and separate out on the "Scenario" pattern and the lines after it, but the problem I'm running into is trying to figure out how to capture the @Tag pattern and write it if it exists above the "Scenario" pattern.

Edit: here is the current relevant part of the script:

```
function writeToTestFile {
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    #if line matches the tag pattern of "@" followed by anything, store it
    if [[ $line == *@* || "" ]]; then
        local tagValue=$line

    #if line in file matches "Scenario:" pattern, write to new file
    elif [[ $line == *Scenario:* ]]; then
        fileToWriteTo=$filename$counter$extention
        ((counter++))
        echo "writing to $fileToWriteTo"
        touch $dirToWriteTo/$fileToWriteTo

    else
        #if line does not match "Scenario:" pattern, check for existing file and write to that
        if [[ -e $dirToWriteTo/$fileToWriteTo ]]; then
            echo "   "$line >> $dirToWriteTo/$fileToWriteTo
        fi
    # if file does not exist and line does match pattern, do nothing
    fi

done < "$1"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file fairly easily with your function in bash. The key is not to worry about looking for the tag lines. Simply look for `Scenario`, having checked/saved the previous tag line each iteration in some variable like `tag`. When `Scenario` is found, check if `tag` exists. If so, write the tagline held in `tag` before `Scenario` and then continue with normal writing of output.

```
#!/bin/bash

function writeToTestFile {
    [ -z "$1" ] && {    ## validate input
        printf "%s() error: insufficient input.\n" "$FUNCNAME"
        return 1
    }
    [ -r "$1" ] || {    ## validate file readable
        printf "%s() error: file not readable '%s'\n" "$FUNCNAME" "$1"
        return 1
    }
    local tag=""    ## use local declarations
    local line=""
    local num=""
    local fname=""
    while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
        if [ "${line// */}" = "Scenario" ]; then    ## check Scenario
            num="${line/Scenario /}"                ## parse num
            fname="File_${num%:}.txt"               ## parse fname
            :> "$fname"                             ## truncate fname
            [ -n "$tag" ] && printf "%s\n" "$tag" > "$fname"  ## tagline
            printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$fname"       ## write Scenario line
        fi  ## write normal lines & update tagline
        [ "${line:0:1}" = " " ] && printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$fname"
        [ "${line:0:1}" = "@" ] && tag="$line" || tag=
    done < "$1"
    return 0
}

writeToTestFile "$1"
```

(**note:** `File_X.txt` is truncated before being written, adjust as required. If there is any chance a line, other than a tag line, begins with `'@'`, you can further anchor the comparison with `"${line:0:4}" = "@Tag"`)

**Input File**

```
$ cat tagfile.txt
@Tag
Scenario 1:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 2
Scenario 2:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 3
@Tag2
Scenario 3:
   Do thing 1
   Don't do thing 4
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash tags.sh tagfile.txt
```

Checking the output files:

```
$ cat File_1.txt
@Tag
Scenario 1:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 2

$ cat File_2.txt
Scenario 2:
   Do thing 1
   Do thing 3

$ cat File_3.txt
@Tag2
Scenario 3:
   Do thing 1
   Don't do thing 4
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk:

```
awk -v MATCH="Scenario 1" '
        !/^[[:space:]]/  {show=0}
        $0==MATCH        {print prev; show=1}
        show             {print}
                         {prev=$0}
    '  input_file
```

That makes several assumptions about the formats which start and end the capture; you might need to adjust the first two conditions.

It would be easy enough to find a similar solution based on your existing bash script. But it would be useful to see the existing bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $i = 0, $t= 0, $fh = 0;

while (<>) {
  if ((/^Scenario/ && !$t) || ($t = /^@\w+$/)) {
    close($fh) if $fh;
    open($fh, '>', "File".++$i.".txt") or die;
  }
  print $fh $_;
}

close($fh) if $fh;
```

Usage: `./script.pl < input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple **awk** solution that incorporates the idea of a `buffer` to hold *@Tag* records immediately prior to *Scenario* records.  It also forms a given `filename` for output from its corresponding *Scenario* record.  Records not part of a *Scenario* are discarded:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        buffer = filename = ""
}
/^@Tag/ {
        if (buffer ~ /./ && filename ~ /./)
                print buffer > filename
        buffer = $0
        next
}
/^Scenario [0-9]+:/ {
        filename=$0
        sub(/^Scenario +/, "File ", filename)
        sub(/:[ \t\r]*$/, "", filename)
}
filename ~ /./ {
        if (buffer ~ /./) {
                print buffer > filename
                buffer = ""
        }
        print > filename
}
END {
        if (buffer ~ /./ && filename ~ /./)
                print buffer > filename
}
```